# Как конвертировать массив в массив из функций, возвращающих число?

Tags: javascript

Допустим, есть массивы `arr1` и `arr2`. Первый массив содержит в себе числа. Нужно переписать его во второй массив так, чтобы тот содержал в себе функции. При вызове `arr2[3]()` получаем тот же результат, что и при вызове `arr1[3]`. 
Я реализовал это так:

```
var arrFunc = [];
function convertArr(arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < (arr.length - 1); i++) {
        arrFunc.push(function(x) { return arr[x] }(i));
    }
}
```

Но в данном случае работает не совсем корректно. Нужно вызывать `arrFunc[3](3)`.

Comment: Так нужно вызывать `arr2[3]()` (в функцию не передаётся параметр) или  `arrFunc[3](3)` (в функцию передаётся параметр, плюс будем полагать, что `arr2` и `arrFunc` - это одно и то же)?

Comment: в моей случае некоректно, то что вызывается с параметром, а по условию нужно без. да, arr2 arrFunc это одно и тоже

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы использовал функцию map:

```
arr.map(function(element) {
    return function() {
        return element;
    };
});
```

или так:

```
arr.map(el => () => el);
```